# Traefik not trusting ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I have had success in both instantiating a traefik container, as well as 4 other nginx containers to serve applications that route my subdomains to each individual service. The routing works, and I am using [acme] for certificate generation, but everytime i try to go to any of my subdomains chrome still gives me an error saying "this connection isn't trusted", and then I have to hit advanced and proceed. The individual applications load fine, but there's something wrong with the certificates.

I have tried clearing the acme.json file to no avail. I had also played around with enabling onDemand in the traefick.toml but that didn't work either.

Please help?

traefik.toml

```
# defaultEntryPoints must be at the top 
# because it should not be in any table below

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]

# http should be redirected to https
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

# https is the default
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"

[entryPoints.https.tls]

# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL
[acme]
email = "chris@myubercode.com"
storage = "./acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
acmeLogging = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "digitalocean"
delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "cswilson.site"
  sans = ["profile.cswilson.site", "ecommerce.cswilson.site", "fitness.cswilson.site", "biosite.cswilson.site"]

traefikLogsFile = "/tmp/traefik.log"
logLevel = "DEBUG"
[accessLog]
filePath = "/tmp/access.log"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "cswilson.site"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

docker-compose.yml (for the traefik container):

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
    networks:
      - default
```

And here is the docker-compose.yml for the 4 different application containers:

```
version: '3'
services:
  profile:
    build: .
    image: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=profile"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:profile.cswilson.site"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoinst=http,https"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "traefik_default"
  fitness:
    build: .
    image: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=fitness"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:fitness.cswilson.site"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoinst=http,https"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "traefik_default"
  ecommerce:
    build: .
    image: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=ecommerce"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ecommerce.cswilson.site"
      - "traefik.port=80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "traefik_default"
  biosite:
    build: .
    image: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=ecommerce"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:biosite.cswilson.site"
      - "traefik.port=80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "traefik_default"
networks:
  traefik_default:
    external:
      name: traefik_default
```

I am new to docker and just found traefik this morning, and I don't really know if I need some sort of a real certificate to put into
[[entryPoints.http.tls.certificates]]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: I'd also like to add that I was trying to check traefik.log and access.log, but for some reason I am unable to "ssh" into the traefik container using docker exec -it traefik_container /bin/bash ..... it just gives an error saying that there is no shell available

Comment: Your site serves the "TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT", which obviously isn't trusted, meaning the actual certificate is never loaded, maybe check this github issue https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2829